# Writing to local file system in Pentaho Server 8 CE

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have used in development a *Text File Output* step in Pentaho 8 CE.
While using the client local installation, output files are written normally to file system.

When I installed the Pentaho Server 8 CE and configured everything to use MySQL as repository, I noticed that system was not writing files to file system.

I suspect that this is because Jackrabbit has been configured to use MySQL as repository following official documentation (https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Setup/Installation/Archive/MySQL_Repository)

1. Is it possible to configure Jackrabbit so all files use the filesystem?
2. If so, where in the documentation is this process documented?
3. Is there any alternative step which forces using local file system?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answers:

1. No.
2. See above.
3. The files can be written, but most likely they’re inside your pentaho-solutions folder inside the server installation. You must use absolute paths when running from the Pentaho repository.

Comment: I finally found that the issue was not related to Jackrabbit but to the fact my "Run configuration" was not properly configured in Spoon. The question is also misleading as I did not clearly state that I was refering to the Step "Text File Output".